# How to display properly sized image from user gallery?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap, android-gallery, bitmapfactory

I am struggling with showing the proper sized images in two of my activities.
The image in the CatalogActivity looks like it is properly scaled down and then cropped while the image in the EditorActivity is whole and is much smaller. 
The only difference is that the image in the catalog comes from image resource while the editor image comes from the gallery so from Uri.

Could you tell me why is this difference and how to make the image from EditorActivity the same as the other one?

From CatalogActivity:

```
// Make the sample image smaller so it doesn't take too much space in the     memory
Bitmap sourdoughBitmap = ProductsEntry.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sourdough_picture, 72, 72);
```

From EditorActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != intent) {
            Uri selectedPictureUri = intent.getData();
            // Show the selected picture in an ImageView in the editor
            try {
                // Scale the bitmap received from the uri so it fits in the small ImageView
                scaledPictureBitmap = ProductsEntry.decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(this, selectedPictureUri, 72, 72);
                // Hide the gray picture placeholder
                mImageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                // Show the scaled bitmap in the ImageView
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(scaledPictureBitmap);
                // The user has chosen a picture and we can change
                // the text of the button to say "Change picture"
                mAddPictureButton.setText(R.string.edit_product_change_photo);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

From ProductsEntry:

```
/**
         * Helps create a smaller bitmap image from resource
         * @param resources - a resources object
         * @param resourceId - the id of the image in the drawable folder
         * @param requiredWidth - the width that we want for the final image
         * @param requiredHeight - the height that we want for the final image
         * @return the decoded Bitmap
         */
        public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources resources, int resourceId,
                                                             int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight){
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds = true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resourceId, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inJustDecodeBounds = false
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resourceId, options);
        }

        /**
         * Helps create a smaller bitmap image from a uri
         * @param context - a context object
         * @param uri - the uri of the image
         * @param requiredWidth - the width that we want for the final image
         * @param requiredHeight - the height that we want for the final image
         * @return the decoded Bitmap
         */
        public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(Context context, Uri uri, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds = true, only to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inJustDecodeBounds = false
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
        }

        /**
         * Calculate a sample size value that is a power of 2 based on a target width and height
         * @param options is used to pass options to the BitmapFactory
         * @param requiredWidth is the width that we want for the final image
         * @param requiredHeight is the height that we want for the final image
         * @return by how much to scale down the image
         */
        private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of the image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > requiredHeight || width > requiredWidth) {

                final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                final int halfWidth = width / 2;

                // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                // height and width larger than the required height and width
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= requiredHeight
                        && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= requiredWidth){
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }
```

From activity_editor.xml:

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/picture"
     android:layout_height="72dp"
     android:layout_width="72dp"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_photo"
     android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Link to the repository [here](https://github.com/maniuni/store-inventory).

Comment: Please put all bitmap resolutions (WxH) in your code so we can compare. Also for sample size and requested sizes.

Comment: Added the missing info in the question at the bottom. Sample size is calculated in the last method, required height is 72 and width 72 dp.

Comment: You have not given the info i asked for.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand exactly what you ask for. Could you explain please?

Comment: Linked the repository below the question, is this enough?